# What does OPT PSEUDOSECTION mean in `dig` response?

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

This is part of the response when I run `dig` in terminal:

```
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
```

What does OPT mean? What does PSEUDOSECTION mean?

Comment: Crosspost https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588558/what-does-opt-pseudosection-mean-in-dig-response . Good thing I didn't find this first and waste my time -- I would consider that rude, greedy, and abusive, and would remember to not ever again do anything that might help you

Comment: It looks like a good question. Why people downvote this post? Does it break some rules?

Comment: @RyanLv When I wanted to post this question, I wasn't sure which StackExchange was most appropriate, so I posted it on two different ones. Turns out that cross-posting like that is a breach of StackExchange etiquette, which I didn't know before now. That's why it was downvoted. I've taken down the other post, which was on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588558/what-does-opt-pseudosection-mean-in-dig-response.

Answer (score 8):

So this has to do with something called Extended mechanisms for DNS (`EDNS`). A DNS message (by which I mean either a request or response) consists of the following five sections that may or may not have values:

```
- Header
- Question
- Answer
- Authority
- Additional
```

In the late 90s, people wanted to extend the functionality of DNS, but because of the way it was built, it was not possible to add more sections to the original list of five, nor to add new flags to the header. So `EDNS` was created, which among other things adds "pseudosections" to DNS. They're called that because they're actually just part of the `ADDITIONAL` section. They're not full sections in their own right, they're just "pseudosections."

`EDNS` also adds support for "pseudo- resource records." So far, only one pseudo- resource record type has been created: OPT, which stands for "options." OPT records don't actually carry any DNS information, just info "pertaining to the question-and-answer sequence of a specific transaction." In other words, they simply contain:

- the version of `EDNS` that is being used
- any `EDNS` flags
- the size of the UDP packet that is carrying the request.

I recommend the wikipedia article on `EDNS` as well as the RFC that introduces it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_mechanisms_for_DNS

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6891